# Phonegap file selection with only images and camera

Tags: image, file, cordova, input

I'm using an input type="file" field in my phonegap mobile app with accept="image/*" set, however the Android file selector keeps showing "Voice Recorder" and "Camcorder" as shown in the screenshot below. Is there a way to fix this without the use of a filepicker plugin? If no, which plugins should I use/are up to date (iOS and android)?

```
<input type="file" name="photo" onchange="myfunc();" accept="image/*;" >
```

Screenshot:
["Choose an action" file selector on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I43Bc.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to upload image from phone memory or from remote server.

Comment: phone memory (like documents in my screenshot) and camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in your code. `accept="image/*;"`. There is a semicolon `;` in your code. The correct way should be like

```
<input type="file" name="photo" onchange="myfunc();" accept="image/*" >
```